# Node 10 vs Node 8 on WSL: different value for getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using the following:

```
var date = new Date(1396576800000);
date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Node 8 on WSL: the offset is 300

Node 10 on WSL: the offset is 360

Is there a workaround for this with my WSL or node configuration?

Comment: Did you try going back to node 8 and see if it changes? What does your browser give you? Is it possible that you accidentally changed you timezone on your machine? Are you in Mountain Time (UTC-07:00)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Node versions. `getTimezoneOffset` depends on locale (host system settings). Maybe you might want to check some environment variable settings.

Comment: @DakotaJang, I believe you are right. I'm running this all in WSL and have been switching between Node 8 and Node 10 using nvm. I tried with Node 10 on Windows and got 300. So... I need to figure out why Node 8 vs Node 10 would return a different value on the same machine. Any idea what I would check?

Comment: @MonkBen It still sounds like you might be running Node 8 and Node 10 in different environments some how. Because there should be no difference in timeZoneOffset between Node versions. Then problem prbably lies in WSL. Maybe check https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3747

Comment: Thanks again @DakotaJang! Yes, that looks very similar to my issue. I'll try updating and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @MonkBen You should update your question if you still have issues. It seems like the problem is not with Node.js but a problem with your WSL setup.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you check these values, this might be due to Daylight Savings Time. The offset difference of 60 strongly suggests this.